# AutoField should be present but it's not (django)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Looking at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save

> For convenience, each model has an AutoField named id by default
> unless you explicitly specify primary_key=True on a field in your
> model. See the documentation for AutoField for more details.

and

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/

it seems clear that an object always has an id. I have a model:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    currency_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    currency_value_in_dollars = models.FloatField()
    currency_value_in_dollars_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.currency_name
```

that I've migrated as:

```
operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Currency',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('currency_name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ('currency_value_in_dollars', models.FloatField()),
            ('currency_value_in_dollars_date', models.DateField()),
        ],
    ),
```

and when trying to add entries to the db like:

```
def update_coins_table():
    if not do_greeting():
        print("Gecko crypto board not reachable. Db setup")
        return

    crypto_coins_prices = cg.get_price(ids=coins_ids_str, vs_currencies='usd')
    timezone_now = timezone.now()
    for coin_key in crypto_coins_prices:
        coin = Currency(coin_key, crypto_coins_prices[coin_key]['usd'], timezone_now)
        coin.save()
```

the line:

```
coin = Currency(coin_key, crypto_coins_prices[coin_key]['usd'], timezone_now)
```

gives:

```
unable to get repr for <class 'manage_crypto_currency.models.Transaction'>
```

and

```
coin.save()
```

fails. If I replace the line in question with:

```
coin = Currency(1, coin_key, crypto_coins_prices[coin_key]['usd'], timezone_now)
```

it works. Shouldn't the id auto increment?

The last line always overwrites the previous and only one entry gets stored in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first *positional* parameter is still the `id`. Whether that is an `AutoField` or not is irrelevant. Especially since Django also uses the constructor to load model objects from the database, and sometimes you *want* to specify the id, because you want to *update* an object.

You can use `None` if you do not want to specify the primary key:

```
#                ↓ use None such that the database will provide an id
coin = Currency(None, coin_key, crypto_coins_prices[coin_key]['usd'], timezone_now)
```

but regardless, the is still "unstable", since adding an extra field somewhere results in the fact that the order of the parameters will change. It is better to use *named* parameters:

```
coin = Currency(
    currency_name=coin_key,
    currency_value_in_dollars=crypto_coins_prices[coin_key]['usd'],
    currency_value_in_dollars_date=timezone_now
)
```

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: Managed to save entries; could have been made slightly more intuitive