# Cannot filter a query once slice has been taken django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Follow up onto:

[AutoField should be present but it's not (django)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64954687/autofield-should-be-present-but-its-not-django/64954724#64954724)

related to:

["Cannot update a query once a slice has been taken". Best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206482/cannot-update-a-query-once-a-slice-has-been-taken-best-practices)

I don't need to filter objects, only order by date and select the most recent one:

```
def get_latest_currency(self):
    """
    Return most up to date value
    """
    up_to_date_currency = Currency.objects.order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:1]

    if not up_to_date_currency.exists():
        # No objects yet; fetch currencies
        update_coins_table()

    return Currency.objects.order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:1]
```

**up_to_date_currency**  is initialized correctly; the last line gives:

```
    assert not self.query.is_sliced, \
AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

This code represents a view (I want to return a plain JSON object (this is a REST endpoint)). Why is django complaining about a filter when only a slice was used?

get_latest_currency is the name of the endpoint:

```
import sys

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'manage_crypto_currency'
urlpatterns = [
    path('get_currency/', views.get_latest_currency, name='index'),
]
```

Stacktrace:

```
Internal Server Error: /get_currency/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 418, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\crypto-currency-board\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 954, in _filter_or_exclude
    assert not self.query.is_sliced, \
AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.
```

Tried wrapping the objects around HttpReponse():

return HttpResponse(Currency.objects.order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:1], content_type='application'
'/json')

This works but only the name is, for some reason, returned.

Comment: Where do you use `get_latest_currency`? It looks like you filter on the *result* of the `get_latest_currency`.

Comment: Could you show the ful ltraceback?

Comment: @Williem It's a view

Comment: @Dmitry Added stacktrace

Comment: The problem is that you use this function as a *view*, but a view should return a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: Tried using HttpResponse but I'm not getting the full entry; only the name (text string) of the currency. It should ideally be a JSON containing the id, currency_name, currency_value_in_dollars_at_date, currency_fetched_date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `QuerySet` as result of a *view*, but a *view* can not return a `QuerySet`. The middleware aims to convert this in a HTTP response hence the error.

Your view thus needs to return some [**`HttpResponse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses). A very simple response would be the `str(…)` of the `QuerySet`:

```
def get_latest_currency(self):
    up_to_date_currency = Currency.objects.order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:1]

    if not up_to_date_currency.exists():
        # No objects yet; fetch currencies
        update_coins_table()

    qs = Currency.objects.order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:1]
    # …
    return HttpResponse(str(qs))
```

You can of course return a more sophisticated result, for example by rendering a template, or returning the result of a serializer.

FOr example if you want to serialize the last object, you can use:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from json import loads as jloads

def get_latest_currency(self):
    up_to_date_currency = Currency.objects.order_by('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')[:1]

    if not up_to_date_currency.exists():
        # No objects yet; fetch currencies
        update_coins_table()

    cr = Currency.objects.latest('-currency_value_in_dollars_date')
    data = serialize('json', [cr])
    return JsonResponse({'data' : jloads(data)})
```

Comment: When using str(query_results) I get <QuerySet [<Currency: neo>]> .

Comment: @Sebi: yes exactly, but the point is you can *not* return a `QuerySet` as result of a view. A HTTP response is always *text*, so you can for example serialize it to a JSON blob, etc. but you can not return a `QuerySet`, model object, etc.

Comment: @Sebi: you can use the `JsonResponse` and the Django serialize to JSON serialize the data.